# No se puede Enviar Correo

Tags: c#, excepciones, smtp

Buenas este es mi codigo:

```
 MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
 msg.To.Add(new MailAddress("xxxxxx@gmail.com"));
 msg.From = new MailAddress("xxxxxx@gmail.com");
 msg.Subject = "Asunto(Correo Prueba)";
 msg.Body = "Contenido Prueba";
 msg.IsBodyHtml = false;
 msg.Priority = MailPriority.Normal;



        SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
        smtpClient.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        smtpClient.Port = 465;
        smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
        smtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("xxxxxxx@gmail.com", "xxxxxx");

ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
                      (s, certificate, chai, sslPolicyErrors) => true;

        //Envio del correo
        try
        {
            //Envio del correo
            smtpClient.Send(msg);
            return "OK";
        }
        catch (SmtpException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            return ex.Message;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            return ex.Message;
        }
        finally
        {
            msg.Dispose();
            smtpClient.Dispose();

        }`
```

No me envia el correo y solo me sale un mensaje que dice Error al enviar correo, ya puse el correo para que permita el acceso desde aplicaciones menos seguras y tambien active el imap que me puede faltar?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, copia y pega el texto exacto del error [editando](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/195855/no-se-puede-enviar-correo#) tu pregunta.

Comment: Estas usando el servicio de smtp, imap no tiene nada que ver porque es para recibir correo, imap es como pop3

Comment: Bueno si imap no tiene nada que ver, ya hice las otras configuraciones del smtp igual no me permite el enviar el correo algo que me pueda estar faltando?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta usando el puerto `587`

```
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient()
{
    Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
    Port = 587,
    UseDefaultCredentials = false,
    Credentials = new NetworkCredential("xx@gmail.com", "password"),
    EnableSsl = true
};
```

[MailMessage - Envia mail con GMail (1/3)](http://ltuttini.blogspot.com/2012/07/mailmessage-envia-mail-con-gmail-13.html)

Comment: ya probe con ese puerto y lo mismo sucedio

Comment: valida que el firewall permite la salida a estos puertos, defines la propiedad UseDefaultCredentials ?

Comment: si defino la propiedad en false, también habilite los puerto en el firewall con una regla para los puerto 587 y 465 aun nada.... lo raro es que solo me pasa en el trabajo en la casa pruebo ese código y me envía el correo perfectamente

Comment: si en tu casa funciona y en el trabajo no, esta claro que no es un problema en el codigo, aconsejaria consultar con alguien de infraestructura si tienes salida a internet sin limitaciones, puede que esten bloqueando la salida en el router de la empresa

Answer (score -1):

Prueba con esta función:

```
 public static
                string EnviarCorreo(string destinatario, string asunto, string cuerpo,
                List<AlternateView> vistas = null)
            {
                try
                {

                    var m = new MailMessage(new MailAddress("identificadorUsuario@correo.com", "NAME"),
                        new MailAddress(destinatario))
                    {
                        Subject = asunto,
                        Body = cuerpo,
                        IsBodyHtml = true
                    };
                    if (vistas != null)
                    {
                        foreach (var item in vistas)
                        {
                            m.AlternateViews.Add(item);
                        }
                    }
                    var smtp = new SmtpClient("correo.algo.algomas")
                    {
                        Credentials = new NetworkCredential("identificadorUsuario@correo.com", "password"),
                        EnableSsl = false
                    };
                    smtp.Send(m);
                    return string.Empty;
                }
                catch (Exception exc)
                {
                    return exc.Message;
                }
            }
```

Comment: ya pobre con la funcion y me devuelve a un error que antes habia llegado

Comment: El servidor SMTP requiere una conexión segura o el cliente no se autenticó. La respuesta del servidor fue: 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. w37-v6sm4548401uaw.35 - gsmtp

Comment: no se porque no estara reconociendo las credenciales me imagino

Comment: realiza una busqueda par ak http://www.mxguarddog.com/es/blog/530-must-issue-a-starttls-command-first/
https://community.liferay.com/es/forums/-/message_boards/message/54111996